# Simple LiteDB query via C# (I'm struggling!)

Tags: litedb

So, I thought I'd give LiteDB a try, but I'm struggling a bit!

Trying to write log data to it. So, what I have so far (simplified)

A class (the data strinture)

```
private class PerBarData
{
    public DateTime ts { get; set; }
    public double o { get; set; }
    public double h { get; set; }
    public double l { get; set; }
    public double c { get; set; }
    public double v { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, double> r { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm writing data to LiteDB like so

```
// Get a collection (or create, if doesn't exist)
var col = db.GetCollection<PerBarData>("PerBarData");

Dictionary<int, double> dict = new Dictionary<int, double>();
for (int i=1; i<maxIndexes; i++)
{
    dict.Add(i,plotBIAS[i]);            
}                       

// Create your new customer instance
var pbd = new PerBarData
{ 
    ts = Time[1],
    o = Open[1],
    h = High[1],
    l = Low[1],
    c = Close[1],
    v = Volume[1],
    r = dict
};

// Insert new customer document (Id will be auto-incremented)
col.Insert(pbd);
```

Which seems to work, as records are in deed being added. I can see that in the LiteDB studio. I can only see what presumably is serialised text though. Objects like this

```
/* 1 */
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "6009b32dfb2026288486321a"}
}
/* 2 */
{
  "_id": {"$oid": "6009b39dfb2026288486321b"}
}
```

So - Presumably, that bit I go right, so far. So, to retrieve some data. All I want, is data between 2 dates, or at least, exceeding one date.  So, I try this

```
DateTime startDate = Time[CurrentBar-1];
DateTime endDate = Time[0]; 
    var col = db.GetCollection<PerBarData>("PerBarData");
    // Use LINQ to query documents (filter, sort, transform)
    var results = col.Find(Query.GTE("ts", startDate));
    foreach(var pbd in results)
    {
        PPrint(pbd.ts.ToString());
    }
```

But, it typically just hangs there. Certainly, no dates are printed. I was originally trying Query.Between and the 2 dates. Same.

Can anyone push me in the right direction please?  I'd really like to give this a proper try.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this rather simply in the end. A replacement of the find query, as follows

`var results = col.Find(x => x.ts >= startDate);`